# How can format HTML with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found a file that I want to read with an unorder HTML code,

There is any visual studio code extension that can fix it to order code?

The code is something like and I want it to look prettier that each tag breaks the line.

```
div><div class="menu"><div class="grid grid-flow-col self-center mx-auto"><div class="cursor-pointer font-bold mx-4"><a href="#ava"><p>text</p></a></div><div class="cursor-pointer font-bold mx-4"><a href="#jarvis"><p>home</p></a></div><div class="cursor-pointer font-bold mx-4"><a href="#faq"><p>FAQ</p></a></div><div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to format, or "beautify" the code in the Visual Studio Code editor using the following:

Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  Linux: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>   macOS: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Alternatively Right click somewhere in the content area (text) for the file
Select "Format Document" from the menu.